# How to transpose particular rows and display the data in below format in unix or python

Tags: python, linux

I have the data in below format.

```
group_name  group_item_fetch
topic_name  fast_events_breaking
topic_lag  0
topic_name  item_fetch_prod_stage
topic_lag  0
topic_name  related_item_re
topic_lag  1018713
group_name fast_processing_events
topic_name item_fetch_processed
topic_lag 109323
```

How to get the output file in below format?

```
group_name,topic_name,topic_lag
group_item_fetch,fast_events_breaking,0
"",item_fetch_prod_stage,0
"",related_item_re,1018713
fast_processing_events,item_fetch_processed,109323
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python `2.7.12`, using `Ubuntu 16.04`, I made this code that gets a file as input, print the result and save it in an out.txt file:

```
import sys

intial_values = []
output = []
file = open('out.txt','w') 

print 'group_name,topic_name,topic_lag'
file.write('group_name,topic_name,topic_lag\n')

for line in sys.stdin:
  intial_values.append(line.split())

is_previous_group = bool
for index, value in enumerate(intial_values):
  if value[0] == 'group_name':
    output.append([
      value[1],
      intial_values[index + 1][1],
      intial_values[index + 2][1]
    ])
    is_previous_group = True
  elif value[0] == 'topic_name':
    if is_previous_group != True:
      output.append([
        '""',
        value[1],
        intial_values[index + 1][1]
      ])
    is_previous_group = False

for value in output:
  print ','.join(value)
  file.write(','.join(value) + '\n')
```

I put the input on a file called `in.txt` with your example:

```
group_name  group_item_fetch
topic_name  fast_events_breaking
topic_lag  0
topic_name  item_fetch_prod_stage
topic_lag  0
topic_name  related_item_re
topic_lag  1018713
group_name fast_processing_events
topic_name item_fetch_processed
topic_lag 109323
```

Using cat and pipe in terminal (I called the python code "filter_rows.py"):

```
cat in.txt | python filter_rows.py
```

The result is as you asked for:

```
group_name,topic_name,topic_lag
group_item_fetch,fast_events_breaking,0
"",item_fetch_prod_stage,0
"",related_item_re,1018713
fast_processing_events,item_fetch_processed,109323
```

Done! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the csv module makes this rather easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import sys


def iter_records(headers, f):
    headers = {name: idx for idx, name in enumerate(headers)}
    last = 0
    record = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(None, 1)
        if headers[key] < last:
            yield record
            record = {}
        record[key] = value
        last = headers[key]
    yield record


def transpose(headers, infile, outfile):
    dw = csv.DictWriter(outfile, headers)
    dw.writeheader()
    for rec in iter_records(headers, infile):
        dw.writerow(rec)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## Usage: ./transpose.py group_name topic_name topic_lag < data.txt
    headers = sys.argv[1:]
    transpose(headers, infile=sys.stdin, outfile=sys.stdout)
```

Note that the format is slightly different in some quoting decision, but if your file is intended to be a CSV, it should not be a problem.